# How to dynamically create object using JQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery

Say, I have an object defined in JavaScript, lets call it 'vision' ; now I'll make an JQuery ajax call and server will return with some integer as response and I have to create that number of new instance of the object 'vision' ; how to do that ?

Comment: I fail to see the problem. It should be as trivial as creating a single new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just use a for loop?

```
//Suppose return_num is the result of your ajax call

for(i=1; i<=return_num; i++) {
  //make vision object
}
```